# Script to check SMB status on multiple servers

Tags: powershell, smb, userscripts

I am looking to check the SMB version and status on a list of servers.  it would be nice to be able to have a list of server, such as a CSV and run the SMBconnection command against each of the servers on the list and output that list to another CSV that shows the results.  Such as, Servername, SMB1 Status, SMB2 Status, SMB3 Status.

Does anyone know how to do this?
I have found this command to detect SMB status but I need to run it against multiple servers.

Detect SMB2 - Powershell command

```
Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB2Protocol
```

Detect SMB1 - PowerShell command

```
Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol
```

Also this one

```
Get-SmbConnection
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'd just use [`invoke-command`](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html) and put the list using `$servers = Get-Content list.txt` into the `-Computername $servers -Scriptblock {<PowerShell Commands>}`. Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3?tabs=server for some more tips. Play with that a bit, try some things, then [edit] to add what you're having trouble with. You have part of what you need, just a bit more digging is needed from your side to narrow it down some more. Please edit once you get there.

Comment: Really, I am just attempting to detect where SMB1 is being used in my enviroment.  I can run the Get-SMBconnection on each of my servers individually, but I am not sure how to write statement to run that command against a list list of servers named "servers".

Comment: You can use something like this as I pointed out. Test it on one server and confirm it works then scale accordingly `Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1,server2,server3 -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB2Protocol, EnableSMB1Protocol  }` or `Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB2Protocol, EnableSMB1Protocol  }`

Comment: The second command worked great!  thanks for the help.  I had something similar but I just didnt understand how the -ScriptBlock Syntax needed.

Comment: After the last `}` you can add a space and then `-Credential (Get-Credential)` to then have that credential run that script block on that server with that server's resources. If you need to run against something with a different credential, that may work too in your environment.